# Ubuntu alias not applied in bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I am under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I have added such line to ~/.bashrc

```
alias myconf="sudo nano /opt/nginx/conf/sites-available/efiling"
```

I tried with single quotes too:

```
alias myconf='sudo nano /opt/nginx/conf/sites-available/efiling'
```

Then I logged out and logged in again.

```
test@STORK:~$ myconf
myconf: command not found
```

But after `test@STORK:~$ source ~/.bashrc` it works.

Can Anyone help me?

Comment: Logout and login and then check the command alias.... it works for me

Comment: It is better to put all your aliases in `~/.bash_aliases` than in `~/.bashrc`. Though technically it won't make a difference, but for administrative purpose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it should be

```
alias myconf='sudo nano /opt/nginx/conf/sites-available/efiling'
```

with single-quotes instead of double-quotes.

You can also use

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

to load `bash.rc` without closing the terminal/logging out.

Comment: Thaks for help. **source ~/.bashrc** helped me. But why it isn't applied automatically when I am logging in?

Comment: Check the file `~/.profile` to see whether `bash.rc` is loaded on logging in.

Comment: ~/.profile contains **if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
 . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi**

Comment: That looks okay. What about the two files `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login`, do these exist on your system? Because in my default `.profile` file the comment at the top says that, "This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login exists."

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. Iy works. It was a problem that I had bash_login file.

Comment: using . in place of source also runs .bashrc doesn't?   >$ .  .bashrc