# Trying to create an alias in Ubuntu 12.10 but it’s not working

Tags: bash, alias

I am trying to create an alias and I have added this line in `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias server-python='open http://localhost:8000 && python -m SimpleHTTPServer'
```

`alias ssh-saad='ssh saad@<my-server>' <my-server>` is replaced by the IP address of my server. So in my `~/.bashrc` file these lines are uncommented

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

and in my `~/.profile`:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

I believe that whenever I start the terminal my aliases should work. However, unless I run the command `source ~/.bash_aliases` it’s not working. Also, for the first `server-python` alias I am getting an error:

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

I have looked into these solutions here:
[How to create a permanent "alias"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias)
[Ubuntu alias not applied in bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176012/ubuntu-alias-not-applied-in-bashrc)

but still cannot make it work. I would really appreciate it if someone could point out to me what I am doing wrong. I know that the problem is very trivial, but I must be just missing something.

---

I have now fixed the error

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

by using `sensible-browser` instead of `open`:

```
alias server-python='sensible-browser http://localhost:8000 && python -m SimpleHTTPServer'
```

Comment: Do the second alias (ssh-aad) work for you? Because I think it has a flaw.

Comment: yes it does work for me can you tell me what is the flaw that you find

Comment: `alias name='commands' something` The something part shouldn't work.

Comment: but its a simple ssh command all I am doing is ssh saad@102.43.2.1 the ip address is just random

Comment: I had understood that you can't pass a argument outside the quotes.

Comment: no I am not passing any arguments I just didnt want to share my ip address thats why i wrote it in that way.

Comment: @Zanna. I am not, myself, inclined to use code markup for error messages. I find blockquote markup more readable. However, if you are going to use code markup, might I suggest that you switch off syntax highlighting? [`<!-- language:  lang-none -->`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/147191)

Comment: @TRiG good point about the syntax highlighting, oops. I disagree about the error output in general, since it's all ruined if there's more than 1 line and the output is likely to have links and file paths, better to put it all in code (if it's from a terminal). Output from APT commands etc is unreadable when blockquoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found one suitable solution for this problem. if there is a `~/.bash_login` file and its not empty then `~/.bashrc` file is not automatically loaded when we open the shell. If we move that `~/.bash_login`

```
mv ~/.bash_login ~/.bash_login_old
```

then `~/.bashrc` file will be loaded and also it will load the `~/.bash_aliases` file if the following lines are uncommented in the `~/.bashrc` file.

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

One other solution I can think of is if you dont want to rename or delete your `~/.bash_login` file then what you can do is when you are in the shell just type this command `bash` and it will load the `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: Having `~/.bash_login` prevents `~/.profile` being sourced, not `~/.bashrc`. You definitely did need to uncomment those lines in `~/.bashrc` though. Typing `bash` opens a new Bash shell which sources `~/.bashrc`. The original shell (started when you opened a terminal) would have done so too, unless it was not a Bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

"open" in ubuntu is `/bin/open`, described by `open -h` as "This utility help you to start a program on a new virtual terminal (VT)."

You the more general thing than sensible-browser  is `gnome-open`, which is not installed by default (anymore?), and is provided by the libgnome2-bin:

```
$ sudo-apt-get install libgnome2-bin
$ gnome-open https://google.com    # opens https://google.com in default browser
$ gnome-open config.txt   # opens config.txt in gedit
```

I find gnome open so useful that I have the following in my (multi-site) bashrc:

```
if which gnome-open >/dev/null ; then
    alias o=gnome-open
elif which kde-open >/dev/null ; then
    alias o=kde-open
elif which xdg-open >/dev/null ; then
    alias o=xdg-open
fi
```

which would let you do:

```
alias server-python="o http://localhost:8000 && python -m SimpleHTTPServer"
```

and it would work most places.

Comment: The "more general thing" is actually xdg-open(1), which is supposed to work on every XDG-compatible desktop environment.

Comment: open is not the main problem here I had solved it by using another command which is sensible-browser. My main problem is that ~/.bash_aliases is not getting loaded automatically when I log into the shell. I have to use this command $ source ~/.bash_aliases, even though the script ( which is in ~/.bashrc)  for automatically loading this file when the shell starts is uncommented.

Comment: Andrea Corbellini: I agree, but gnome-open seems to sometimes to a better job of hooking into gnome preferences. But as you might notice I do hook into it if gnome-open isn't available.

Comment: Saad: have you tried `"$HOME/.bash_aliases"` instead of `~/.bash_aliases`? Also, have you tried just doing `if [ -f "$HOME/.bash_aliases" ] ; then echo yes ; else echo no ; fi`?