# Terminal does not recogninze an installed program

Tags: xfce4-terminal

I am new to linux and am using xubuntu.

I have successfully installed maple 13 on my machine and its working fine. The problem is when ever I need to start maple, I have to do it through double click-- since typing `maple` or `xmaple` in terminal does not work the same as opening firefox by just typing `firefox` in terminal.  Why?

I want my terminal to open maple 13 when some command like `maple` or `xmaple` is typed.

Comment: I have updated my answer with edit.

Comment: "Does not work"? What happens?

Comment: Now with the edit of .bashrc I am getting "bash: alias: xmaple: not found bash: alias: =: not found bash: alias: /home/sohail/maple13/bin/xmaple: not found"

Comment: @searchfgold6789 I get command not found.

Comment: I edited @rajagenupula 's answer. Try it with the minor syntax fixes.

Comment: Thanks @rajagenupula and searchfgold5789. Its working now. I think now I should be able to do this procedure for my matlab as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal and paste these lines

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /home/sohail/maple13/bin/xmaple /usr/local/bin
```

then try again.

**Edit:**

type in your terminal as

```
gedit .bashrc
```

and write

```
alias xmaple='/home/sohail/maple13/bin/xmaple'
```

Save & close.
Type `bash` in your terminal and run `source ~/.bashrc`.
Then type `xmaple`.

Comment: After changing maple9.5 to maple13 in the above suggested commands, nothing happened.

Comment: whereis maple return /usr/local/bin/maple

Comment: Moreover, the launcher is somewhere here: /home/sohail/maple13/bin/xmaple

Comment: ""sudo ln -s /home/sohail/maple13/bin/xmaple /usr/local/bin/maple"
        gives
        "ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/maple': File exists"

Comment: @Sohail What happens when you run `maple` in a terminal?

Comment: No command 'maple' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ample' from package 'ample' (universe)
maple: command not found
sohail@sohail-Inspiron-N5110:~$ maple
No command 'maple' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ample' from package 'ample' (universe)
maple: command not found

Comment: Now with the edit of .bashrc I am getting "bash: alias: xmaple: not found
bash: alias: =: not found
bash: alias: /home/sohail/maple13/bin/xmaple: not found"

Comment: @Sohail http://askubuntu.com/questions/176012/ubuntu-alias-not-applied-in-bashrc

Comment: @rajagenupula, After logging out and then in and then typing $source ~/.bashrc I am still getting alias not found as indicated above.